# Non Parsable POM for spring-boot-starter-parent

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

Spring boot pom.xml file is giving `error at line 1, Project build error: Non-parseable POM J:\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.8.RELEASE.pom: end tag name </head> must be the same as start tag <link> from line 39 (position: START_TAG seen ...nk rel="stylesheet" href="styles.9fb46a4e844d7fbc314e.css"></head>... @39:70)`

Checked out project from spring initializer website. Imported the same project into eclipse workspace. I guess, this issue introduced after spring 2.1.7.RELEASE. I'm not sure any maven changes or something got changed.

Ideally the project should get build without any errors.

Comment: Combining a cleanup of your project and the directory of your build tool (~/.m2/repository) should do the job. Spring-boot 2.1.8 works for me. Could you maybe share the invalid file with us? Or publish a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Looks like you are getting HTML response instead xml, this may be because of proxy. Are you behind any http proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the pom for the spring starter is somehow corrupt for you.
Check the file at `J:.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.8.RELEASE.pom:`
And see if the file is still valid.

To fix just delete everything in .m2/repository folder. Maven will redownload the dependencies

Comment: Can you post the content of that mentioned pom?

Answer (score 0):

Can you follow the step

1. If you can access repository , Just just delete that m2-folder.
2. Can you Remove  installed artifact for that version from your  local
   repository.